# memory allocation in collection of 1 million references in java

Tags: java, memory-management, arraylist, reference, linked-list

I created an ArrayList of 1 million MyItem objects and the memory consumed was 106mb(checked from Task Manager) But after adding the same list to two more list through addAll() method ,it takes 259mb. My question is I have added only the references to list , no new objects are created after that 1 million.why does the memory consumption increase eventhough LinkedList has been used (as it wont require contiguous memory blocks so no reallocation will be made)?

How to achieve this efficiently?  Data passes through various lists in my program and consuming more than 1GB of memory.Similar scenario is presented above.

```
public class MyItem{
private String s;
private int id;
private String search;

public MyItem(String s, int id) {
    this.s = s;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getS() {
    return s;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}


public String getSearchParameter() {
    return search;
}

public void setSearchParameter(String s) {
    search = s;
}
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<MyItem> l = new ArrayList<>();
        List<MyItem> list = new LinkedList<>();
        List<MyItem> list1 = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000 ; i++) {
            MyItem m = new MyItem("hello "+i ,i+1);
            m.setSearchParameter(m.getS());
            l.add(i,m);
        }

        list.addAll(l);

        list1.addAll(l);
        list1.addAll(list);

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        s.next();//just not to terminate 
    }
}
```

Comment: The ArrayList bases as indicated by it's name on an array. If the array gets too small a new array, double of size is created and the references are copied to the new array. As Java has it's own memory management the memory of the first array will be released only JVM internal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LinkedList` is a [doubly-linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list), so elements in the list are represented by nodes, and each node contains 3 references.

From Java 8:

```
private static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> prev;

    Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

Since you use a lot of memory, you may not be using compressed OOP, so references might be 64-bit, i.e. 8 bytes each.

With an object header of 16 bytes + 8 bytes per reference, a node occupies 40 bytes. With 1 million elements, that would be 40 Mb.

Two lists is 80 Mb, and then remember that Java memory is segmented into pools and objects (the nodes) gets moved around, and your memory consumption of an additional 153 Mb now seems about right.

Note: An `Arraylist` would only use 8 bytes per element, not 40 bytes, and if you preallocate the backing array, which you can do since you know the size, you would save a lot of memory that way.

Answer (score 5):

Anytime you call [`LinkedList.addAll`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) behind the scene it will create a [`LinkedList.Node`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.Node) for each added element so here you created **3 millions of such nodes** which is not free, indeed:

1. This object has 3 references, knowing that the size of a reference is `4 bytes` on `32-bit JVM` and `64-bit JVM` with `UseCompressedOops` (-XX:+UseCompressedOops) enabled which is the case by default with heaps less than `32 GB` in Java 7 and higher and `8 bytes` on `64-bit JVM` with `UseCompressedOops` disabled (-XX:-UseCompressedOops). So here according to your configuration it gives **12 bytes** or **24 bytes**.
2. Then we add the size of the header fields which is `8 bytes` on `32-bit JVM` and `16 bytes` on `64-bit JVM`. So here according to your configuration it gives **8 bytes** or **16 bytes**.

So if we summarize it takes:

1. **20 bytes** per instance on `32-bit JVM`
2. **28 bytes** per instance on `64-bit JVM` with `UseCompressedOops` enabled
3. **40 bytes** per instance on `64-bit JVM` with `UseCompressedOops` disabled

As you call 3 times `addAll` of 1 Million objects on a `LinkedList`, it gives

1. **60 Mo** on `32-bit JVM`
2. **84 Mo** on `64-bit JVM` with `UseCompressedOops` enabled
3. **120 Mo** on `64-bit JVM` with `UseCompressedOops` disabled

The rest is probably the objects not yet collected by the garbage collector, you should try to call `System.gc()` after loading your `ArrayList` to get the real size and do the same thing after loading your `LinkedList`.

If you want to get the size of a given object, you can use [SizeOf](http://sizeof.sourceforge.net/).

If you use a `64-bit JVM` and you want to know if `UseCompressedOops` is enabled, simply launch your java command in a terminal with only `-X` options and adds `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | grep UseCompressedOops` so for example if my command is `java -Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=4g -cp <something> <my-class>`, launch `java -Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=4g -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | grep UseCompressedOops`, the beginning of the output should look like this:

```
     bool UseCompressedOops                        := true            {lp64_product}
     ...
```

In this case the flag `UseCompressedOops` is enabled

Comment: I thought LinkedList.Node will be assigned with the reference! If not how can i work without allocating more nodes ;(  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It is what it does but it creates an instance of LinkedList.Node for each added elements to keep the previous and next node